# Is there a performance hit to using UIImageViews of different size/scale than the actual image?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, retina-display

I'm lazy loading images from the web and tossing them into UIImageViews that I create in a Nib. On a retina iPad the images that are scaled down look a lot better than the images at their normal resolution. Even though they look better those images *have* to be resized which would cause a performance hit, right? Should I make the UIImageViews the size of the UIImages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images should not be resized to the size of the image view, but to `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` * `imageView.size`. On a retina screen, the scale is 2, but it is probably best practice to use the screen scale instead of hard coding.

Setting it to this precise size will require the fewest cycles (and thus get the best performance) on render.

Comment: Isn't imageView.size in 'points', rather than 'pixels' as unit? If it's in 'points' (which, until now, I thought was the thing), then [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] will not be required, right?

Comment: yes, but in the mathematic operation to get pixels for the image sizing, the concept of "points" is lost so you need to pull out the scale